# Derive Expectation/Variance of Histogram

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, variance, expected-value, moment-generating-function

> Derive the expectation and variance of the following:
>   $\frac{1}{n(b-a)}$$\sum_{i=1}^n 1$$_{Y_i∈(a,b]}$, b>a.

My thoughts with this are to put the summation in an integral and then multiply by n. Is this a correct way of thinking? Is a moment generating function needed?

Comment: welcome to the site. Have you been given any information on $Y$ like its distribution? If not, you'll need to use some results about the empirical process.

Comment: Hint: when $Y$ is any random variable, $X=1_{Y\in(a,b]}$ is a random variable that can take on only the values $0$ and $1$: that gives it a Bernoulli$(p)$ distribution where $p=\Pr(X=1)$. If you assume the $Y_i$ are independent and can find the $p_i$ associated with each $Y_i$ you will have all the information you need to solve this problem.  If you don't make assumptions, then please tell us what you do know about the joint distribution of the $Y_i$.

Comment: @whuber Well, you know all the probabilities are equal, and the expected value of a bernoulli is just the probability, so it becomes n*1/n(b-a) which just gives you 1/(b-a), a uniform distribution. Is this thinking correct?

Comment: Your algebra can't be right: notice that the $p_i$ didn't appear anywhere in your answer.  When you compute the variance you will also have to consider the covariances between the $Y_i$, so you need to make some assumption about those.  I believe the notation might be confusing you, too: the sum $n$ of Bernoulli variables can take on only the values $1, 2, \ldots, n$.  It will never be uniform and no longer has any explicit connection to the interval $(a,b]$.